# gcc asm with empty input operand constraint

Tags: assembly, gcc, inline-assembly

When using extended asm in gcc, it is clear and documented what this does:

```
__asm__ ("some instructions" : /* No outputs */ : "r" (var));
```

It asks gcc to place var into a register and pass it to me as %0. It also creates a dependency on var, such that this instruction will not be moved prior to the last point var was changed, not will it be moved relative to other volatiles (which is another documentation subtlety).

What's not clear is what this does:

```
__asm__ ("" : : "" (var));
```

My first initial thought is that the empty constraint might be the same as "X" - ie: put it anywhere. But it isn't. For me (using Arm cortex), the "X" or "r" places var in, say, r4. The "" does not.

It creates the same ordering dependency but doesn't appear to do anything else. Which might be the intent but is this documented anywhere?

Comment: Where does it put the operand?  What string does GCC substitute into the template, e.g. if you do `"@  operand was %0"`?  (Or `"nop @ %0"` so Godbolt doesn't filter it: https://godbolt.org/z/KPcoYa).  It seems GCC will freely pick wherever it currently is, even if that's memory, so perhaps equivalent to `"g"`.  But since it's undocumented, it's unsupported and just a "happens-to-work" thing.

Comment: That's an answer and I completely agree. I saw it being used somewhere and I thought "that's interesting".
But you are right - it may be a "happens-to-work" thing or maybe not. But it's unsupported so it could easily change; relying on the behaviour would be foolhardy to say the least! Edit: That's very revealing godbolt output, thanks for that.

Comment: An empty constraint is (was?) allowed in a theoretical architecture that doesn't need constraints, where any kind of valid operand can be used for any operand, but I don't GCC actually has any such architectures.  The VAX architecture was supposed to allow this, but I think they implemented some constraints anyway for performance reasons.